# Can't write command in adb shell

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When I want use "adb shell" command to connect to my API level 16 AVDs, I have problem. because it respond just a "#" in new line of terminal and it's not possible to write any command. 
Just as the image

[image]

I don't have this problem with my API level 22 or 23 AVDs.

Must I change some settings of avd or something else?

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the device?

Comment: What do you mean? What should I do?

Comment: `adb -s emulator-5554 shell`

Comment: I tied it now and again it responded nothing. just a "#".

Comment: Is it the terminal of your IDE? Try to connect to the device from your OS - Linux/termianl, Windows/command.

Comment: I suggest to try a new emulator image, maybe this instance of AVD got corrupted.

Comment: @TDG Yes, It's Android Studio terminal. But trying windows cmd has same result.

Comment: I created other instances and got same result @AlexCohn

Comment: Another option could be that you somehow downloaded a broken image. Try to remove the API-16 system image from SDK manager, and download a new one.

Comment: try an old adb in your PC